# JSONdecoder Error in Python 3. Json from API

Tags: python, json

I have a code:

```
dguid='2016A0011M4B'
income='7'
ethnic='3'
language='10'
url = 'https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/rest/census-recensement/CPR2016.json?lang=E&dguid={}&topic={}&notes=1'.format(
    dguid,
    ethnic)

!wget -q -O 'data.json' url
with open('data.json') as json_data:
data = json.load(json_data)
```

**It gives me an Error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yg9f.png)

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         9 get_ipython().system("wget -q -O 'data.json' url")
>        10 with open('data.json') as json_data:
>   ---> 11     data = json.load(json_data)
>
> /opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/**init**.py in
>   load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant,
>   object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>       266         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
>       267         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
>   --> 268         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>       269 
>       270
>
> /opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/**init**.py in
>   loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int,
>   parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>       317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
>       318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
>   --> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>       320     if cls is None:
>       321         cls = JSONDecoder
>
> /opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in
>   decode(self, s, _w)
>       337 
>       338         """
>   --> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>       340         end = _w(s, end).end()
>       341         if end != len(s):
>
> /opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python35/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in
>   raw_decode(self, s, idx)
>       355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
>       356         except StopIteration as err:
>   --> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>       358         return obj, end
>
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

what is wrong?

Comment: If I use loads instead of load method it will give me Error: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper'

Comment: `!wget -q -O 'data.json' url` does not look like valid Python code...

Comment: There are some data science notebook interactive interfaces such as Jupyter/Ipython that support running shell commands like that (in the middle of python code, for example). Like this: https://twitter.com/python_tip/status/929984742421942272/photo/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON returned by that URL is not valid. This is clearly identified by the exception.

The JSON payload has a prefix of "//" that renders the JSON invalid:

> **//**{"COLUMNS":["PROV_TERR_ID","PROV_TERR_NAME_NOM",...

You must strip these first 2 characters. You can do it like this:

```
with open('data.json') as json_data:
    line = json_data.readlines()
    line[0] = line[0][2:]
    data = json.loads(line[0])
    print(data)
```

Tested correctly om python 3.6.1